# Error when running Azure Functions project in Visual Studio with --useHttps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I was trying to figure out a way to run azure functions project with https in Visual Studio using AF v1 with C#.

Under Debug section in the project settings, I put "host start --useHttps" in Application arguments and then tried running the application.

In the console it shows "The host is taking longer than expected to start."

There are no errors shown. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why? That's not how it works once deployed to Azure Functions.
No TLS traffic will reach the function as crypto is handled in the frontend tier.

[image: App Service TLS offload]

Comment: The question is how, not why. Anyway, our Web UI client runs in https and makes requests to the Azure Functions backend and it cannot do so if the backend doesn't run on https. We need it for local development.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify a cert/key combo (PFX) as well via `--cert`? The docs do say that it will automagically create a trusted cert in your store, but it's not clear to me if that's v1 or v2 host.

Comment: This works for v2, `func host start --useHttps --cert ../certs/joescrabshack.pfx --password xxxxx`, should be similar to v1 unless something dramatically changed.